# Give role to specific user using DiscordjJS 14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Data fetched from interaction

```
if (interaction.commandName === 'give-role') {
    const userID = interaction.options.getUser('username');
    const roleName =interaction.options.getRole('role');
    }
```

Give Roles command

```
const GiveRolesCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('give-role')
    .setDescription('Give role to some user')
    .addUserOption((option) =>
        option
            .setName('username')
            .setDescription('Enter discord user to give role to')
            .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addRoleOption((option) =>
        option
            .setName('role')
            .setDescription('Role name to give to user')
            .setRequired(true)
    );
```

How do I give the fetched role to the fetched user from the interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a user and role objects not an ID or name. 
Nonetheless use `interaction.members.cache.get(user.id)` to get a guild member object. 
 At last use `Member.roles.add(role)`

 One-Liner: `interaction.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(role)`